# What is a forum in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request

The word "forum" as used in English and many other modern languages obviously comes from Latin.
It means a place where people gather to discuss, like an online forum or a scientific conference, but not a place of commerce.
The Latin *forum* means a marketplace or an outside or public area.
Is *forum* the best match for the English "forum" (with more or less equivalent reincarnations in other languages), or is there a better choice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Caesar and Cicero refer to *collŏquĭum* in association with *convenio* vb and *convenium* noun.

> a talking together, conversation, conference, discourse. (W Smith 1895)

exemplum

> *collŏquĭum quum conveniunt in unum locum loquendi causa* Varr L.L. 6,7,66.

and from Caesar B. G. 1

> eo ad colloquium venerunt
>   in colloquium venire.

Is that too formal?

Comment: This looks great! Formality is no problem, and *colloquium* doesn't strike me as very formal anyway.

Answer (score 4):

English in this context has a number of words that might originally have suggested something rather different. We speak of the Republican Party *Convention*, the Trades Union *Congress*, the *Synod* of the Church of England, the Welsh National *Assembly*, the *Council* for the Preservation of Rural England and so on. It wouldn't be stretching it too far to say that these are all forums of one kind or another.

Going into Latin, however, the most frequent word for a forum in the sense apparently needed here is *conventus*, basically meaning an 'assembly', a 'conjunction', a 'coming together', in almost any sense, and it's probably the most suitable word for 'forum' as the word is nowadays used.  It appears far more often in word-searches than *conventio*, being much favoured (if that's the right word) by both Caesar and (especially) Cicero. A word like *conventio*, *congressio* or *colloquium* is tempting because of similarity in current English, but each seems to have had a restricted use, whereas *conventus* can be applied to any kind of gathering, including that of people for discussion and other kinds of interaction.